# How to prevent 429 (Too Many Requests) error using setTimeout

Tags: javascript

I am using a service to replace the words of an article with synonyms, the API of the service has a limit of 60 requests per minute. I have two functions, the first one get the article and split it into an Array, then calls the other to replace the words, I tried to do that by setting timeout to the second so it will be called first and then after 60 seconds, and then after 120 secs... so every minute I will call the service at most 60 times.

```
generateArticle : function(data){ 
  Art.words = data.split(" ");
  for(var j=0; j<Art.words.length/60; j+=1){
    setTimeout(Art.generateSector(j*60),j*60000);
  }
},

generateSector : function(position){
  var count = 0;
  for(var i=position; i<Art.words.length; i+=1){
    if(Art.words[i].length > 3 && isNaN(Art.words[i]) && count < 60){
      Art.findsimilarword(Art.words[i],i);
      count++;
    }
  }
},
```

but what is happening is that the second function is called immediately, so in an article with 400 words the first 60 words will be replaced correctly but for the rest 340 words I am getting an error `429 (Too Many Requests)` . Am I using the setTimeout with a wrong way? Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
setTimeout(Art.generateSector(j*60),j*60000);
```

***calls*** `Art.generateSector` *immediately*, passing in `j*60`, and then takes its *return value* and passes it to `setTimeout`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` *calls* `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`.

To schedule a call to the function, you pass in a function reference. In your case, you can probably use `Function#bind`:

```
setTimeout(Art.generateSector.bind(Art, j*60),j*60000);
```

`Function#bind` returns a new function that, when called, will call the original with the given value as `this` (in our case, `Art`) and any additional arguments you provide.

---

`Function#bind` is an ES5 feature. If you have to support really old JavaScript engines like the one in IE8, this feature can be "shimmed" ("polyfilled"). Search for "function bind shim" or "function bind polyfill" to find multiple options.

Comment: or ...`setTimeout(function (){Art.generateSector(j*60)},j*60000);` since http://jsbin.com/axaluq/44?q=bind

Comment: @RoyiNamir: No, with that code the callback will use the wrong value for `j`.

Comment: sorry `setTimeout(function (a){ return function (){Art.generateSector(a*60)}}(j),j*60000);`

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Right. But there's no reason to create and throw away a temporary builder function on every loop like that in addition to the function we're creating for `setTimeout`. Just use `bind`, that's what it's for.